# Likelihood function and MLE

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

Please let me know how to find the likelihood function and MLE when the data have density $f(x; \theta ) = ( \theta +1) x^\theta$.

I have tried using the general formula however not sure how to proceed further with that.

Comment: You need to specify also the range of $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a probability density function
$$ f(x|\theta) = (\theta + 1)x^{\theta},$$
the likelihood, $L(\theta|x)$, is defined as
$$ L(\theta|x) = \prod_{i = 1}^{N}(\theta + 1)x_{i}^{\theta},$$
and the corresponding log-likelihood, $\Lambda(\theta|x)$, is defined as
$$ \Lambda(\theta|x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \text{log}(\theta + 1) + \theta \text{log}(x_{i}).$$

If you want the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE), you need to find the maximum of the log-likelihood function:

$$0 = \frac{\partial\Lambda(\theta|x)}{\partial\theta} = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \frac{1}{\theta + 1} + \text{log}(x_{i}) = \frac{N}{\theta + 1} + \sum_{i = 1}^{N}\text{log}(x_{i})$$

Comment: Thank you. So the MLE will be the above expression or is there a way we can customize the equation. Do I need to find anything from the last expression, please advise

Comment: I added a little "customisation"... Anyway, where did you find such a probability density function?

Comment: Thanks a million. I was referring the past papers where i find this one. Not sure where it is applied.